# What does "trait A <: B" mean?

Tags: inheritance, scala, traits

In Scala, what does

```
trait A <: B
```

mean? Is it just the same as

```
trait A extends B
```

?

**Edited to add:** I'm familiar with the syntax for type parameters, and what `<:` means in that context. However, in the above example it would seem to me that `A` is the name of the trait being declared, not a type parameter.

Comment: I think it means that B is smiling at A

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**NOTE** As of Scala 2.12.5 using `<:` for `extends` is deprecated

```
scala -deprecation -e 'trait B; trait A <: B'
/var/folders/0w/kb0d3rqn4zb9fcc91pxhgn8w0000gn/T/scalacmd2374381600671257557.scala:1: warning: Using `<:` for `extends` is deprecated
trait B; trait A <: B
                 ^
one warning found
```

---

Seems to compile to the same thing.

```
 ~/code/scratch: scala -Xprint:typer -e 'trait B; trait A <: B'
          // snip
          abstract trait B extends scala.AnyRef;
          abstract trait A extends java.lang.Object with this.B

 ~/code/scratch: scala -Xprint:typer -e 'trait B; trait A extends B'
          // snip
          abstract trait B extends scala.AnyRef;
          abstract trait A extends java.lang.Object with this.B
```

The spec doesn't explain this in "5.3.3 Traits". But the Syntax Summary does mention this.

```
TraitDef ::= id [TypeParamClause] TraitTemplateOpt 
TraitTemplateOpt ::= Extends TraitTemplate | [[Extends] TemplateBody]
Extends ::= ‘extends’ | ‘<:’
```

**UPDATE** It was introduced in [r14632](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/14632/scala/trunk/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Parsers.scala). With the compiler option `-Xexperimental` it marks the trait as abstract, for use with a proposed language feature [Virtual Traits](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/export/20327/scala/branches/devel-base-2.8.0/SIP/virtual-traits/sip-0000X.xhtml). Without `-Xexperimental`, it is a synonym for 'extends' that is allowed only for traits.

Comment: Depends which part of the spec you look at! The syntax summary appendix says, "Extends ::= ‘extends’ | ‘<:’"

Answer (score 11):

The <: syntax is reserved for future use in virtual classes (which are not implemented yet).

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), it seems to mean the same thing. The description for trait only mentions the `trait A extends B` syntax. But the Scala syntax summary uses `extends` and `<:` interchangeably for trait definitions:

```
TraitTemplateOpt ::= Extends TraitTemplate | [[Extends] TemplateBody]
Extends ::= ‘extends’ | ‘<:’
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, well, almost, see [this article](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-5) for a little more information. From the [language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), we see the following definition:

> We define two relations between types.
>
> Type equivalence   T ≡ U   T and U are interchangeable in all contexts.
>
> Conformance    T <: U  Type T conforms to type U .

**Edit**: Looking into the language spec it appears that `<:` and `extends` are the same, in particular it is defined as:

```
ClassTemplateOpt ::= Extends ClassTemplate | [[Extends] TemplateBody]
TraitTemplateOpt ::= Extends TraitTemplate | [[Extends] TemplateBody]
Extends ::= ‘extends’ | ‘<:’
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that as of Scala **2.12.5**:

> Using `<:` for `extends` is deprecated

```
$ scala -deprecation -e 'trait B; trait A <: B'
/var/folders/0w/kb0d3rqn4zb9fcc91pxhgn8w0000gn/T/scalacmd4147407032094171597.scala:1: warning: Using `<:` for `extends` is deprecated
trait B; trait A <: B
                 ^
one warning found
```