# What does "<:" mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm looking at p. 469 of "Programming in Scala" Second Edition.  There is a line of code that reads:

```
type Currency <: AbstractCurrency
```

I cannot decipher what this means.

Comment: See also [What does “trait A <: B” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123663/what-does-trait-a-b-mean)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It means an abstract type member is defined (inside some context, e.g. a trait or class), so that concrete implementations of that context must define that type. However, there is a constraint that this type (`Currency`) must actually be a *subtype* of `AbstractCurrency`. That way the abstract context can operate with `Currency`, knowing that it understands every operation of `AbstractCurrency`.

```
trait AbstractCurrency {
  def disappearInGreece(): Unit
}

abstract class Economy {
  type Currency <: AbstractCurrency

  def curr: Currency

  // can call disappear... because `Currency`
  // is an `AbstractCurrency`
  def shake(): Unit = curr.disappearInGreece()
}
```

Trying to define `Currency` without constraints:

```
trait RadioactiveBeef

class NiceTry(val curr: RadioactiveBeef) extends Economy {
  type Currency = RadioactiveBeef
}
```

Fails. With constraints ok:

```
trait Euro extends AbstractCurrency

class Angela(val curr: Euro) extends Economy {
  type Currency = Euro
}
```

Answer (score 50):

It means "must be a subtype of", "must conforms to", "must extends". 
Most of the time, it would appear as a bound on a generic parameter, such as

```
class Home[P <: Person]
```

Each Home is fit for a certain type of person, a `Home[Person]` accepts any person, there might be `Home[Student]`, `Home[Elderly]`, but no `Home[Planet]`.

`type Currency <: AbstractCurrency` introduces an abstract `type` member `Currency` in the `class`/`trait` where it appears. Descendants will have to choose a type so that they can be concrete. The <: AbstractCurrencies force them to choose a subtype of `AbstractCurrency` (including `AbstractCurrency`, which is allowed).

An abstract type member is very close to a type parameter, just as an abstract value member is close to a constructor parameter.

If you have `class A(val x: X){...}`, you instanciate the first with `new A(myX)`. If you have `class A{val x: X; ...}`, you instanciate with new `A{val x = myX }`.

If you have `class Market[Currency <: AbstractCurrency]` you instanciate the type with `Market[SomeCurrencyType]`. If you have `Market{type Currency <: AbstractCurrency}`, you instantiate with `Market{type Currency = SomeCurrencyType}`. However, `Market` is a valid type. It means you don't know what type of currency this market uses (which may restrict how you can use it).

Using an *abstract type member* rather than a type parameter may have benefits, mostly if the type parameter does not appear in the public interface of the type, if `Market` has no `Currency` appearing as a function parameter or result (not too likely on this example). Then client does not need to write `Market[SomeCurrencyType]`, `Market` will do. Of course, the `CurrencyType` will have to be known when a market is created, but then it may be passed along simply as `Market`.

Answer (score 15):

I want to add some points which will describe the usability benefits of the <: notation.

Let us say, you define the following class for your API:

```
case class myApiClass[param <: BaseParameter](requestBody: String, parameter: param)
```

You have a trait called BaseParameter

```
trait BaseParameter
```

Then, you have the following parameters:

```
case object Parameter1 extends BaseParameter
case object Parameter2 extends BaseParameter
case object Parameter3
```

Now, whenever you create a myApiClass instance, you must pass an object as the argument "parameter", whose class/which itself implements BaseParameter (e.g. Parameter1 and Parameter2). Concretely, this is an assertion, and would not work if you pass Parameter3.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for - the reason, not just what it does!

Comment: The following also would provide same behaviour right ?

case class myApiClass(requestBody: String, parameter: BaseParameter)

Answer (score 8):

This question is about Scala but I think it's worth mentioning that the `<:` [type operator?] is not unique to Scala and instead originates in Type Theory; see for example the article about [Subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) on Wikipedia which makes extensive use of this operator.

In fact, due to its strong connections with type theory `<:` is not the only thing Scala (elegantly) borrowed from it; for example the `term: Type` notation (seen in e.g. `val foo: Foo`, `def fact(x: Int): Int`) also comes from [Type Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question